# ¿Cómo llamar correctamente a funciones en C++?

Tags: c++, funciones, programación-funcional

Estoy haciendo un programa que multiplique entre sí los números ingresados por el usuario.

El programa debería preguntar cuántos números el usuario quiere multiplicar entre sí y luego pedir que los inserte uno por uno para hacer la multiplicación.

No aparece ningún error al compilar, sin embargo no funciona . Creo que hay un problema al momento de llamar funciones, pero no puedo identificarlo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int listaNumeros[10];
int i,n, producto=1;

void leerNumeros(int listaNumeros[10]);
int productoNumeros(int listaNumeros[10]);

main(){
    
    printf("Ingresa el numero de elementos a multiplicar entre si \n");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    int leerNumeros ();
    int productoNumeros();
    printf("%i",producto);
}


void leerNumeros (int listaNumeros[]) {
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Ingrese el numero ");
        scanf("%i", &listaNumeros[i]);
    }
    
}
    
int productoNumeros(int listaNumeros[]) {
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        producto=listaNumeros[i]*producto;
        return producto;
    }
}
```

Comment: leerNumeros no esta recibiendo ningun parametro

Comment: Esto no es C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos revisando el código, partiendo de una versión "correcta":

```
#include <stdio.h>

void leerNumeros(int lista[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Ingrese el numero ");
        scanf("%i", &lista[i]);
    }
}

int productoNumeros(int lista[], int n) {
    int producto = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        producto = lista[i] * producto;
    }
    return producto;
}

int main() {

    int listaNumeros[10];
    int n;
    printf("Ingresa el numero de elementos a multiplicar entre si \n");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    leerNumeros(listaNumeros, n);
    int producto = productoNumeros(listaNumeros, n);
    printf("%i", producto);
    return 0;
}
```

**Análisis**

*Variables globales*

Hay que evitar las variables globales. Se prestan para confusiones, especialmente cuando usas la misma variable global "i" en múltiples lugares del código.

En este caso, movi todas las declaraciones para hacerlas locales, y use la forma `"for (int i=0 ..."` para declarar una variable "i" local al `for`.

Recomendación: Declarar las variables dentro de la función o bloque que las usa.

*Parámetros de funciones*

Las funciones tienen que recibir sus datos vía parámetros. Así las podrás ocupar con más de un argumento. Usar variables globales para pasar parámetros es mala idea.

Entonces, la declaración de `leerNumeros` y productoNumeros necesitan incluir la lista de números y su largo. Por tanto, los declaro asi:

```
void leerNumeros(int lista[], int n) 

int productoNumeros(int lista[], int n)
```

Lo que se interpreta asi: La funcion `leerNumeros` recibe una lista de enteros (largo no declarado) y un entero. La función `productoNumeros`, lo mismo, y retorna un valor entero.

Recomendación: escribir la función antes del main para evitar declaraciones extras.

*Error de lógica*

```
int productoNumeros(int listaNumeros[]) {
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        producto=listaNumeros[i]*producto;
        return producto;
    }
}
```

El `return` está mal puesto, pues se ejecuta en la primera iteración del `for`.

**Error en uso**

Las instrucciones en el `main`

```
int leerNumeros ();
int productoNumeros();
```

no ejecutan las funciones, simplemente las declaran como funciones sin parámetros que retornan enteros (lo que no es cierto, tampoco).

Comment: Oh, vaya. ¡Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Candid! Me aclaraste muchas dudas que tuve al momento de intentar hacer el código. Tomaré todos tus comentarios en cuenta la próxima vez. Muchas gracias 